# Android auth: how to store/access user credentials in google app engine?

Tags: java, android, api, google-app-engine

I am creating a login system for my android app. I want following to
    happen:

```
1. User enters username/password.
2. Login button sends request to custom API in google app engine.
3. App engine performs a check in google cloud sql if the user entered correct credentials or not.
4. If user entered correct credentials then response comes as a valid access token and user logs in successfully.
```

I am no able to find a way to achieve above goal. I am new to APIs and login system. I need to know how to create an api that can read the request and do a check and return the result.

Comment: You meant `how do i save the token received from google and later use the same again right, rather than showing the consent screen multiple times?`

Comment: try this example http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: @Ranjith No, the whole thing. If there is any tutorial on how to create a Login API and accessing api from app engine.

Comment: are you set on using Cloud SQL? because this could be achieved using endpoints in minutes.